# boost::hana tag_of implementation

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, partial-specialization

I wonder how the `when` specialization work when there's no case base for the `boost::hana::when<false>` case.

`boost::hana::tag_of` implementation:

```
 template<bool condition>
 struct when; // forward declaration only

 template<typename T, typename = void>
 struct tag_of;

 template<typename T, typename>
 struct tag_of : tag_of<T, when<true> >
 {};

 template<typename T, bool condition>
 struct tag_of<T, when<condition> >
 {
    using type = T;
 };
```

And a test example:

```
 struct my_tag {};
 struct my_tag2 {};

 namespace boost {
    namespace hana {

       template<class T>
       struct tag_of<T, when<std::is_same<T, int>{}()> >
       {
           using type = my_tag;
       };

       template<class T>
       struct tag_of<T, when<std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}()> >
       {
          using type = my_tag2;
       };
    }
}

int main()
{
   using type = boost::hana::tag_of<int>::type;
   std::cout << std::is_same<type, my_tag>{} << std::endl;
}
```

and I wonder why `std::is_same<T, int>{}()` (or with `::value` which is the same), is a more specialized partial specialization than `std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}()`, and why, if the condition is false for both cases, `when<condition>` is more specialized.

I have done a lot of metafunctions and work with specializations and parameter packs and the sort, but in this case, there's something that I don't see.

The thing is that I don't see why the `true` or `false` value of the `when` template can matter, if there's no default implementation for the `false` case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and I wonder why `std::is_same<T, int>{}()` (or with `::value` which is the same), is a more specialized partial specialization than `std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}()`, and why, if the condition is false for both case, `when<condition>` is more specialized.

It's *not* more specialized. They're simply never both viable specializations. Let's walk through what happens when we try to instantiate `hana::tag_of<int>`.

1. Fill out the default template arguments. In this case, the 2nd template parameter defaults to `void`, so we really have `hana::tag_of<int, void>`.
2. Consider which partial specializations are viable. In this case, *none* of them are viable - our type (`int`) isn't a reference or cv-qualified and it isn't any kind of `when<condition>`. Since none of the specializations are viable, we instantiate the primary template.
3. The primary `tag_of<T, void>` inherits from `tag_of<T, when<true>>`. So now we need to instantiate that second type, which means we redo step #2.
4. Now, two different specializations are viable:

   ```
   // from hana's core
   template <typename T, bool condition> 
   struct tag_of<T, when<condition>>

   // yours
   template <typename T>
   struct tag_of<T, when<std::is_same<T, int>{}()>>
   ```

   Note that your other specialization *is not viable* - because `std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}` is `false` and we're trying to match `when<true>`.
5. Between those two specializations, yours is more specialized if we go through the partial ordering rules - so it's selected and instantiated.

Hence, `hana::tag_of<int>::type` is `hana::tag_of<int, void>::type` is `hana::tag_of<int, when<true>>::type` is `hana::tag_of<int, when<std::is_same<T, int>{}()>>::type` is `my_tag`.

---

> The thing is that I don't see why the `true` or `false` value of the when template can matter, if there's no default implementation for the `false` case.

The above hopefully illustrates why it matters. We're not instantiating `when<false>` directly, but you could write a specialization which substitutes into `when<false>` (like your `when<std::is_same<T, unsigned>{}()>` specialization).

> and why, if the condition is `false` for both cases, `when<condition>` is more specialized.

Since we're instantiating `when<true>`, those specializations whose condition is `false` are simply excluded from the candidate set. The list of viable specialization is just reduced to the one that hana provides directly. It's not "more specialized" - it's solely viable.

---

Also worth noting that `tag_of` gives you multiple ways to specialization. You can either provide some boolean condition *or* use `void_t`. Or, you could just specialize top-level:

```
template <>
struct tag_of<int, void> {
    using type = my_tag;
};
```

That would short circuit at step #2 above, skipping all the other instantiations.

Comment: It's amazingly beautiful. Thanks.